# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, 16.04, qt5, pyqt5

I try to run a python script using PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets but it throws errors:

```
  from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import (
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

I think there is a package missing but which one? `python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit` is installed.

How to get this working?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% certain that this addresses the OP's error message, but at least for Ubuntu 17.04 I have successfully run:

```
apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine
```

This brings in loads of dependencies, including `libqt5webenginecore5`, `libqt5webenginewidgets5`, `python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel` and `python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine`.

I do not know how this relates to @The Compiler's answer of **QtWebEngine** not being packaged for Ubuntu, but it worked for me without any compiling of Qt/PyQt.

Comment: This solved my problem of using Anki flashcard on Debian

Comment: I've tagged 16.04 so it's not exactly the answer but good to know, it's available in current LTS release (18.04 does have it too).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, when trying to run Spyder for the first time. I'm using a Miniconda distribution on Mac. I had to install both so that I could lunch Spyder

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
pip install PyQt5
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

The script needs QtWebEngine, not QtWebKit.

Unfortunately, that's [not packaged for Debian/Ubuntu](https://marc.info/?l=kde-core-devel&m=142954900813235&w=2), so the only way you would get that running is to compile Qt and PyQt on your own (which can be a bit of a pain).

Comment: I think so too... :(

Comment: What about for Windows?

Answer (score 4):

I installed `python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia`

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
```

in Xenial (because `python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine` was not found, so I searched all patterns matching `python3-pyqt5` and `apt-cache search` found this one among others which seemed relevant to me.

I can now use `ffmpegconverter` again! (A small one which does great things, which I compiled by hand).

Comment: But what does this have to do with my question?

Answer (score 3):

> If you get here and are using pip - I haven't investigated fully but I just got just this when running Anki since the upgrade in pip to PyQT5 5.12. The package sizes for 5.11.3 and 5.12 are vastly different - 5.11.3 weighs in at 118MB and 5.12 at "only" 61MB. Forcing the install of 5.11.3 removed the issue. I'm guessing this is no longer bundled in the PyQT5 in pip, and needs to be installed as a separate requirement.

It's in the [release notes](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/pyqt-512), they moved the webengine widgets to a different package. Just run:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get here and are using pip - I haven't investigated fully but I just got just this when running Anki since the upgrade in pip to PyQT5 5.12. The package sizes for 5.11.3 and 5.12 are vastly different - 5.11.3 weighs in at 118MB and 5.12 at "only" 61MB. Forcing the install of 5.11.3 removed the issue. I'm guessing this is no longer bundled in the PyQT5 in pip, and needs to be installed as a separate requirement.

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip install PyQt5==5.11.3
```

(Anki's requirements.txt has now been updated, so pulling the latest from Github should now work)

Comment: Can you expand your answer and show the commands needed to do this?

Comment: Done, sorry it took so long

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by running this command:

```
pip3 uninstall pyqt5
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openshot-qt/+bug/1814520

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 running 64-bit version of Python 3.8.0, I found this to work:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
pip install PyQt5==5.13
pip install PyQtWebEgine
```

Now your code will not complain about QtWebEngineWidgets import error.