# OpenShot video editor doesn't open

Tags: apt, package-management, python, video-editor

I installed OpenShot video editor by using `sudo apt install openshot` from the official repository, then I tried to open it by using `openshot-qt` command and it camed errrors, here's the output:

```
Compiled translation resources missing!
Loading translations from: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/language
Loaded modules from installed directory: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt
      launch:INFO ------------------------------------------------
      launch:INFO    OpenShot (version 2.4.3)
      launch:INFO ------------------------------------------------
         app:INFO openshot-qt version: 2.4.3
         app:INFO libopenshot version: 0.2.2
         app:INFO platform: Linux-5.4.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
         app:INFO processor: x86_64
         app:INFO machine: x86_64
         app:INFO python version: 3.8.5
         app:INFO qt5 version: 5.15.2
         app:INFO pyqt5 version: 5.15.2
     metrics:ERROR Error determining OS version in metrics.py
    language:INFO Qt Detected Languages: ['en-US', 'en']
    language:INFO LANG Environment Variable: en_US.UTF-8
    language:INFO LOCALE Environment Variable: 
    language:INFO OpenShot Preference Language: Default
project_data:INFO Setting default profile to HD 720p 30 fps
ZmqLogger::Connection - Error binding to tcp://*:5556. Switching to an available port.
ZmqLogger::Connection - Error binding to tcp://*:5556. Switching to an available port.
         app:INFO Setting font to Cantarell
logger_libopenshot:INFO Connecting to libopenshot with debug port: 5556
         app:INFO Setting custom dark theme
  exceptions:ERROR Unhandled Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openshot-qt", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('openshot-qt==2.4.3', 'gui_scripts', 'openshot-qt')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py", line 98, in main
    app = OpenShotApp(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/app.py", line 157, in __init__
    from windows.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/main_window.py", line 43, in <module>
    from windows.views.timeline_webview import TimelineWebView
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/timeline_webview.py", line 40, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

^C      logger:ERROR Exception ignored in:
      logger:ERROR <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py'>
      logger:ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
      logger:ERROR   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1388, in _shutdown
      logger:ERROR lock.acquire()
      logger:ERROR KeyboardInterrupt
      logger:ERROR :
```

I am using UBUNTU 20.04.

Comment: You can download `Openshot` from the Ubuntu Software Center. It works fine on 20.04.2

Comment: @24601, after I installed openshot with apt it says it's installed in software center.

Comment: Oh my god - using `sudo openshot-qt` works, but not `pxexec openshot-qt`, why?

Comment: because you're running it as root.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/3890

Comment: @Hermann, thanks but now it throws error RELATED TO https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/3615

Comment: The error is finally gone in Openshot 2.6.0 :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openshot not opening in Ubuntu 18.04, No module named PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273119/openshot-not-opening-in-ubuntu-18-04-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwebkitwidgets)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem(openShot not launching in ubuntu 22.04)

1. add the OpenShot PPA repository to our Ubuntu 22.04 using the below command.

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:openshot.developers/libopenshot-daily
   ```

When prompted, click the ENTER command to proceed with adding the PPA

2. Once the PPA repository is added, we can then use the apt command to fetch the openshot-qt package and install it with the below command.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
   ```

And after that, `openshot` worked very well.

Comment: Unfortunately this has stopped working. There is a bug-report thread:
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openshot-qt/+bug/1971094